# %1 in registry not being expanded in Windows 8

Tags: command-line, windows-8, windows-registry, prompt, command-line-arguments

I have made a tool that adds some things to the context menu when right clicking a directory, inside the 'empty space' of a directory, or a drive. I have used this extensively in Windows XP, Vista, and 7, but now that I've upgraded to Windows 8 I'm having an issue with getting the directory that the command was launched from.

One of the things I add is "Command Prompt Here", and I have accomplished this with the following in an INF file:

```
HKCR,Directory\Background\Shell\CommandPromptHere\command,,,"""%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe"" /c cmd /s /k ""VER && PUSHD ""%1"""""
```

This adds the following in a REG_EXPAND_SZ key:

```
"%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe" /c cmd /s /k "VER && PUSHD "%1""
```

Since this wasn't working, (couldn't find cmd.exe), I tried replacing it with:

```
cmd /c cmd /s /k "VER && PUSHD "%1"
```

In the Windows 7, Vista and XP, "%1" gets expanded to the directory who's background was right-clicked. However, it's not working in Windows 8. Even trying to echo it back to the command line doesn't seem to be working.

I can get "%cd%" to expand when I use "ECHO %cd%", but I can't seem to use it to start the command prompt there ("PUSHD %cd%" isn't working).

Has something changed with the arguments in Windows 8? Is there some other reason it's not working? Is there another way to "Start a command prompt in the current directory" with a registry entry? Am I missing something?

The code is here: https://github.com/Ehryk/ContextMenuTools for further details or suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you just Shift + Right Click to get "Command Window Here"? And the "" at the end of your second example looks a bit odd.

Comment: 1) I don't want to shift + right click
2) I use this to also add Git Bash prompt, PowerShell Prompts, and also launch them as administrators
3) I do other things to the cmd prompt like set window title, color text red for admin prompts, etc.

The double quotes get rendered as single quotes in the registry key.

Comment: Yes but I would have expected to see something like (again, in the second example) `"%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe" /c cmd /s /k "VER && PUSHD ""%1"""`

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, for whatever reason %1 isn't populated when using the /Background/ commands in Windows 8 as it is in Windows 7.

I got around it by using:

```
cmd /c cmd /s /k "VER && @cd "%%%CD%%%"
```

Any insight as to why this changed is very welcome.